# VBA Excel Getting Run-time error 91 once UserForm is unloaded

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a UserForm however once I click CommandButton1 (ok) or CommandButton2 (cancel) I always get an error.

**Error Message**

Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set

**Debugging**

I have checked my code to the best of my knowledge. I searched the 'similar questions' when typing this question but nothing. I have also Debug-Compile without errors. I'm at a lose..

**Code**

*Please note: all code below is within the UserForm*

```
Option Explicit
Private FirstSunday As Date
Private SecondSunday As Date


Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.value = True Then: CheckBox2.value = False
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    If CheckBox2.value = True Then: CheckBox1.value = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If CheckBox1.value = True Then
       MsgBox "First Sunday"  ' testing - variable to be used in SAP macro
       Unload Me
    ElseIf CheckBox2.value = True Then
       MsgBox "Second Sunday"  ' testing - variable to be used in SAP macro
       Unload Me
    Else
        MsgBox "No date selected. Please select a date or press 'Cancel'.", 0 + 48 + 0, "Error - No selection"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    GetSundayDates

    With frmMthEndDate
        With .Question
            .Caption = "Please select the last Sunday of " & Format(FirstSunday, "MMMM") & " Month-End then click the 'OK' button."
            .Font.Size = 8
        End With
        .CommandButton1.Caption = "OK"
        .CommandButton2.Caption = "Cancel"
    End With

    With CheckBox1
        .Caption = FirstSunday
        .Font.Size = 8
    End With
    With CheckBox2
        .Caption = SecondSunday
        .Font.Size = 8
    End With

    Me.Show

End Sub

Private Sub GetSundayDates()

    Dim WeekdayInteger As Long
    WeekdayInteger = Weekday(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), vbMonday)

    Dim MinusDays As Long
    Select Case WeekdayInteger
        Case 1:  MinusDays = -1 ' Mon
        Case 2:  MinusDays = -2 ' Tue
        Case 3:  MinusDays = -3 ' Wed
        Case 4:  MinusDays = -4 ' Thu
        Case 5:  MinusDays = -5 ' Fri
        Case 6:  MinusDays = -6 ' Sat
        Case 7:  MinusDays = 0 ' Sun
    End Select

    FirstSunday = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), MinusDays - 7)
    SecondSunday = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), MinusDays)

End Sub
```

**edit adding sub calling form**

```
Sub TestingForm()

    frmMthEndDate.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Which line is highlighted when it errors?  If no line, make you sure have "Break in class module" set in your VBA error handling settings.  Remove the `:` after the `Then` in those methods.  You can use a single line `If Then` statement but it doesn't work over two lines (which is what the : gives you)

Comment: No line is highlighted when it breaks. I changed from 'unhandld erros' to 'break in class' and reran but same error message. Also removed `:` and same error

Comment: is `frmMthEndDate` the name of your form?  If so, try changing all of those to `Me` inside your form's code module.

Comment: The strange thing is when the error pops up, there is no `debug` button.. only `ok` and `help`

Comment: Yes it is.. changed `frmMthEndDate` to `Me` and same error

Comment: Is there no Debug button, or is it greyed out?

Comment: no debug button

Comment: Copied this form to a new workbook and ran, same error

Comment: Any error handler in the code launching the form?  How exactly are you launching it?

Comment: place cursor inside `UserForm_Initialize` and press `F5`

Comment: Try launching the form from another sub in a regular module.

Comment: see edit in question. ran from a regular sub. get same error but now when i click on debug it highlights `frmMthEndDate.Show`

Comment: You shouldn't need that line?

Comment: by removng `Me.Show` from `UserForm_Initilaize` it now works without error

Comment: good to hear you got it fixed